# Multiple values with .childAdded in Swift and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to code a notification system in my app. In order to explain my problem simply, let's say that when a user like a picture there is a new notification child in Firebase. If the same user unlike the picture, the child is removed.

The database structure is like that:

```
|
| Notification
|   |_UserID (the one who received the notification)
|   |  |__NotificationID
|   |  |  |_from: UserID (the one who sent the notification)
|   |  |  |_notViewed: false
|   |  |  |_objectId: "-L5-C7nnEji4tNeJp3Ca"
|   |  |  |_timestamp: 1518286167
|   |  |  |_type: "like"
```

The idea is that I observe all the notifications within the root Notification/CurrentUser:

```
func observeNotification(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Notificationm) -> Void) {
          REF_NOTIFICATION.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                   let newNotif = Notificationm.transformNotification(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)

                   completion(newNotif)

                }
          }
}
```

And then, in the ViewController:

```
func loadNotifications(){
    Api.Notification.observeNotification(withId: currentUser.uid) { (notification) in
       print(notification.id)
    }
}
```

My problem is simple, but I really don't understand the reason:

- If call the function loadNotifications() with a refresher, everything is okay
- **If the database change (for example, there is a new notification) everything is multiplied! The same notification can be printed 2, 3, 4, etc. times!** I really don't understand why.

If I use another account, to like and unlike my picture. I can see that:

- the first time, the notification is showed in 3 times
- The second time -> 6 times
- The third time -> 9 times

It can affect the others notification, which can be showed in 2 or 4 times.

I'm new in Swift, and really lost.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it looks like maybe you are accidentally creating multiple observers... OR are accidentally calling more than one completion function... OR you are accidentally observing ALL cumulative notifications instead of only the most recent one.  I would recommend using print debugging to A) determine exactly when your functions are being called, and B) that your variables (such as snapshot) contain what you expect them to contain at any given time.  OR... you could hope that Frank van Puffelen shows up and sees your question! :)

Comment: Hi @BooberBunz ! Thanks to your reflexion, I found a way to resolve my problem. I'm sure it's not the best resolution but it's working :) I used -> if let _ = self.notifications.first(where: {$0.notification.id == notifUser.notification.id}) in order to see if the notification was already added or not